# Subtle CSS gradient animations

Tags: jquery, css, radial-gradients

I'm trying to make an animated background gradient similar to the one on Interweave's website here: https://interweaveagency.com/ but made out of CSS and jQuery onto a background element rather than a canvas element. I've made something like this in a fork from another codepen:

https://codepen.io/Jamie-Patterson/pen/rNrWXKL

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
var colors = new Array(
  [17,17,17],
  [17,17,17],
  [17,17,17],
  [187,238,0]);

var step = 0;
//color table indices for: 
// current color left
// next color left
// current color right
// next color right
var colorIndices = [0,1,2,3];

//transition speed
var gradientSpeed = 0.002;

function updateGradient() {
  var c0_0 = colors[colorIndices[0]];
  var c0_1 = colors[colorIndices[1]];
  var c1_0 = colors[colorIndices[2]];
  var c1_1 = colors[colorIndices[3]];

  var istep = 1 - step;
  var r1 = Math.round(istep * c0_0[0] + step * c0_1[0]);
  var g1 = Math.round(istep * c0_0[1] + step * c0_1[1]);
  var b1 = Math.round(istep * c0_0[2] + step * c0_1[2]);
  var color1 = "#"+((r1 << 16) | (g1 << 8) | b1).toString(16);

  var r2 = Math.round(istep * c1_0[0] + step * c1_1[0]);
  var g2 = Math.round(istep * c1_0[1] + step * c1_1[1]);
  var b2 = Math.round(istep * c1_0[2] + step * c1_1[2]);
  var color2 = "#"+((r2 << 16) | (g2 << 8) | b2).toString(16);

    $('#gradient').css({background: "-webkit-radial-gradient(80% 10%, circle, "+color1+", transparent), -webkit-radial-gradient(80% 50%, circle, "+color2+", transparent)"});
    
    step += gradientSpeed;
    if ( step >= 1 )
    {
      step %= 1;
      colorIndices[0] = colorIndices[1];
      colorIndices[2] = colorIndices[3];
      
      //pick two new target color indices
      //do not pick the same as the current one
      colorIndices[1] = ( colorIndices[1] + Math.floor( 1 + Math.random() * (colors.length - 1))) % colors.length;
      colorIndices[3] = ( colorIndices[3] + Math.floor( 1 + Math.random() * (colors.length - 1))) % colors.length;
      
    }
} setInterval(updateGradient,10);
```

});

But it lacks the subtlety I've been trying to achieve as it shifts heavily from one gradient to another rather than the more lavalamp effect from the Interweave site. If anyone's built something similar out of CSS/jQuery before and has a solution let me know.

Comment: I didn't create any code, but you might consider replacing the RGB color coding with a HSL version. Rotating the 'color wheel' a few degrees, adjusting saturaration and lightness percentages will give you much more control over your colors and the palette they're in. Well worth your time investigating the difference between RGB and HSL color coding.

Comment: Just a comment - you might want to consider whether you really want to do this. On the canvas example it takes massive amounts of GPU (up to 90%) on my reasonably powerful laptop so could be a real battery flattener on a user's phone, and although it takes less with the CSS example it's still substantial (around 45%).

Comment: ☝️ might be a reason to go for a subtle 'white'...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a plain CSS implementation you can adapt.

For the subtlety, create a larger background, e.g. 400%, and move it around. See `.bg1`

For the light and dark gradients, they look to me as transparently layered, so I'm adding a second div with a semi-transparent highlight. See `.bg2`

```css
body,
html {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.container {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  position: relative;
}

.bg1,
.bg2 {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;

}

.bg1 {

  animation: bg1 8s ease infinite;
  animation-direction: alternate-reverse;
  background: linear-gradient(-45deg, #ee7752, #e73c7e, #23a6d5, #1cb693);
  background-size: 400% 400%;
}

@keyframes bg1 {
  0% {
    background-position: 100% 50%;
  }

  100% {
    background-position: 0 50%;
  }
}

.bg2 {
  animation: bg2 5s ease infinite;
  animation-direction: alternate-reverse;
  background: radial-gradient(rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9), rgba(255, 255, 255, 0));
  background-size: 100% 200%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

@keyframes bg2 {
  0% {
    background-position: 0% 100%;
  }

  100% {
    background-position: 100% 0%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="bg1"></div>
  <div class="bg2"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: This looks good - but sadly still taking huge amounts of my GPU (around 85%) so I wouldnt want it to run for long if on a battery.

Comment: @AHaworth how are you measuring the GPU usage?

Comment: Task manager in Windows 10

Comment: @AHaworth in my M1 Pro it uses ~20% (in fullscreen)